# FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line number 48

Tags: php

I have this "FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line number 48", can't figure why? I'm total php beginner. :)

```
    public function __construct ($order, $params=array()) {
        $this->order_info=$order;
        $this->params = ( !empty($params) ) ? $params : $this->params;
    }

    public function sendMessage($phone_number, $msg_text){

            $phone_number = trim(str_replace(" ", "", $phone_number));          
            $user = $this->params['user'];
            $password = $this->params['password'];
            $senderID = $this->params['sender'];
            $curl = curl_init();
            $query_string = "http://gateway80.onewaysms.sg/api2.aspx?apiusername=".$user."apiusername&apipassword=".$password."&senderid=".$senderID."&mobileno=".$phone_number."&message=".rawurlencode(stripslashes($msg_text))."&languagetype=1"
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->$query_string); // here is the error
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            echo $result;
            return new stdClass;
     }
```

Thank you for your help.

Cheers

Comment: yo man `"&languagetype=1"` <<<<<<<<<<< Google your errors.

Comment: `// here is the error` - don't believe everything PHP tells you. It's the one "above".

Comment: @fred-ii- why do you always pop up & beat me to the punch.. stop being so quick!

Comment: @DarylGill I type faster?

Comment: I've tried with google....Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `;` at the end of $query_string declaration.

```
$query_string = "http://gateway80.onewaysms.sg/api2.aspx?apiusername=".$user."apiusername&apipassword=".$password."&senderid=".$senderID."&mobileno=".$phone_number."&message=".rawurlencode(stripslashes($msg_text))."&languagetype=1";
```

Comment: Thanks you :) cheers